# Chrome extension to inject JS into a sandboxed iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, webrtc, sandbox

I am working on a Chrome extension to block WebRTC against this flaw: https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips

All good with the current code until until a few days ago when the exploit was updated to include this: `iframe.sandbox = 'allow-same-origin';`
Since the  sandbox attribute was added, I am getting the error `Blocked script execution in 'about:blank' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.`

What to do?

Relevant code from manifest.json:

```
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "run_at": "document_start",
        "all_frames": true,   
        "match_about_blank": true,
        "js": ["webrtc.js"]
    }
],
 "permissions": [ "tabs", "<all_urls>", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking"],
```

My webrtc.js:

```
 var inject = '(' + function() {
        if (typeof window.RTCPeerConnection !== "undefined") {
            window.RTCPeerConnection = undefined;
        }
        if (typeof window.webkitRTCPeerConnection !== "undefined") {
            window.webkitRTCPeerConnection = undefined;
        }
    } + ')();';
var isInIFrame = window.frameElement && window.frameElement.nodeName == "IFRAME";
    if(isInIFrame==true){
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.textContent = inject;
        (document.head || document.documentElement)
        .appendChild(script);
        script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
    }
else
    {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.textContent = inject;
        (document.head || document.documentElement)
        .appendChild(script);
        script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
    }
```

LE:  I forgot to add that the extension doesn't block WebRTC in latest stable build  40.0.2214.111, but it seems to do so in the Canary 42.0.2304.0.

Comment: Sounds potentially like a bug. I'd also ask on https://crbug.com

Comment: W.r.t. your update, seems like a _fixed_ bug and nothing you can do until it hits stable.

Comment: I am not an expert, but does it mean that if one adds iframe.sandbox = 'allow-same-origin' to an iframe, extensions just won't work in that iframe? Meaning that extensions like adblockers would become completely useless for such iframes?

Comment: Your test seems to be flawed, because the script is still blocked in Chromium 42.0.2305.0.

Comment: @RobW as noted in the later edit, with current Canary build (42.0.2305.0 c as tested earlier), the extension is working and WebRTC is blocked. Not sure what's flawed, actually: the extension or Google Chrome stable (as user Xan suggested earlier) ?

Comment: @ArturW. I showed that with the latest version of Chrome (42.0.2305.0 = just a few hours old), the issue as reported in your question still exists. If you think that this behavior is a bug, create a bug report at crbug.com/new, as suggested by Xan.

Comment: @RobW I am confused because I just tested several times on Chrome 42.0.2305.0 and it doesn't show any IPs leaked via WebRTC. It does with the stable build 40.0.2214.111 m, though.